# How can I make a hyperlink work in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

When I add www.stackoverflow.com into my RichTextBox and run the program it is shown in blue and as a hyperlink yet when I click it nothing happens. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762271/clicking-hyperlinks-in-a-richtextbox-without-holding-down-ctrl-wpf is the best thread for this I found (so far)

Answer (score 140):

1. Make sure the text property includes a valid url. E.g. http://www.stackoverflow.com/
2. set the **DetectUrls** property to **true**
3. Write an event handler for the **LinkClicked** event.

Personally, I wouldn't pass **"IExplore.exe"** in as a parameter to the **Process.Start** call as Microsoft advise as this presupposes that it is installed, and is the user's preferred browser. If you just pass the url to process start (as per below) then Windows will do the right thing and fire up the user's preferred browser with the appropriate url.

```
private void mRichTextBox_LinkClicked (object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for UNC, paths like E:\My Documents\Logs\log1.log ?

Comment: @Kiquenet - not sure, but try using an entry of the form file:////e:/My%20Documents/Logs/log1.log

Comment: This can be a grave security risk. A better way is: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", e.LinkText);`

Comment: Just to reiterate the point @Christian is making -- **explorer.exe** passes the arguments to a singleton, which is guaranteed running un-elevated.  Running the command yourself it may or may not be elevated.  If explorer runs it un-elevated, and it needs elevation, the UAC will ask.  Much safer.

Comment: I use this and the system throws the error ['The system cannot find the file specified' when clicking link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74732645/3416774)

Answer (score 10):

RichTextBox class allows you to customize its behavior when user clicks the hyperlink.  Add an event handler for the [RichTextBox.LinkClicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.linkclicked.aspx)  event

```
Process p = new Process();

private void richTextBox1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
   p = Process.Start("IExplore.exe", e.LinkText);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that `DetectUrls` is set to `true`. If that doesn't work on its own, you may need to add a handler for the `LinkClicked` event.

Comment: Unable to find DetectUrl property in RichTextBox

Comment: The DetectUrl property is only in the WinForms version of RichTextBox. The WPF version does not have this property. Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762271/clicking-hyperlinks-in-a-richtextbox-without-holding-down-ctrl-wpf

Answer (score 1):

Is `yourTextBox.DetectUrls` set to true?  We may need some more info to provide a better answer.