# WPF RichTextBox support for document links?

Tags: .net, wpf, richtextbox

I'm attempting to render RTF documents using the WPF RichTextBox control.  So far, the appearance of the rendered RTF documents is quite true to the originals which were authored using MS Word.

The one issue I've found is that the "document anchors" which are hyperlinks to different locations within the document, do not function as hoped.  While they look like links, clicking on them does nothing.

Can the WPF RichTextBox support this type of link?

Comment: See this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762271/clicking-hyperlinks-in-a-richtextbox-without-holding-down-ctrl-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the WPF RichTextBox control cannot support document links.