# Hyperlink in WPF Richtextbox

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, richtextbox

I load WPF Richtextbox contents from Xaml string in which there are some Hyperlinks. When it is loaded into control, Hyperlinks are not clickable! I want to click on them and their associated URL shows up.

Comment: use this:
`richTextBox.IsDocumentEnabled = true;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No [freschx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275452/freschx), it's about **WPF**. **A WPF `RichTextBox`**, unlike the one in WinForms, **does not have a `DetectUrls` property**. And it's weird you wrote a Xaml code for that, even weirder there is someone who thought it useful.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762271/clicking-hyperlinks-in-a-richtextbox-without-holding-down-ctrl-wpf) out where [JHubbard80](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772243/jhubbard80) and me had two different approaches to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To make the `Hyperlink`, or any inline `UIElement` in general, available for hit testing, we must set `RichTextBox.IsDocumentEnabled` to `true`.

To make the `Hyperlink` clickable without pressing the ***Ctrl*** key, the `Hyperlink` must be made read-only e.g., by wrapping it into a `TextBlock` or by making the complete `RichTextBox` read-only (by setting `RichTextBox.IsReadOnly` to `false`).

```xml
<RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True">
  <FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
      <Run Text="Some editable text" />

      <TextBlock>                
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://duckduckgo.com">
          DuckDuckGo
        </Hyperlink>
      </TextBlock>
    </Paragraph>
  </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: "Hyperlink must be made read-only"  No, it's possible to make hyperlink clickable especially in run time codebehind like following new Hyperlink(rtbxTextArea.Selection.Start, rtbxTextArea.Selection.End) wrapping is not needed. But the thing is somehow it's not clickable if same document is loaded back. It's needed to be reset when loadig back.

Comment: @livan3li This statement is related to the *interaction behavior* and not about making the Hyperlink clickable in the first place. Of course, it is clickable by default, anything else would be strange. Without the span that contains the hyperlink being configured as read-only the user would have to press Ctrl to enable click navigation. That's the default behavior. Otherwise, you will just move the cursor focus into the RichtextBox to the clicked position, allowing the user to edit the content. I was never saying that the Hyperlink is not clickable otherwise. Just read carefully.

Comment: @livan3li The complete and relevant quote is: *"To make the Hyperlink clickable __without__ pressing the Ctrl key [...]"*. Be aware that your provided solution is performing *extremely* bad. The FlowDocument, and especially the RichtextBox, is a *very* heavy control. You definitely should avoid your approach. It doesn't scale at all.

Comment: @livan3li It's also important to understand that the Hyperlink behavior is defined by the hosting parent. The Hyperlink object itself does not navigate anywhere.