# WPF hyperlink in RichTextBox click event

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, richtextbox

I want to add a hyperlink to a RichTextBox, then navigate to another window when the link is clicked.

This is what I have:

```
 // Add paragraphs to the FlowDocument
 Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
 link.IsEnabled = true;
 Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
 myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
 link.Inlines.Add(reviewAuthor);
 link.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.link_Click);
 paragraph.Inlines.Add(link);
 richTextBox.Document = myFlowDoc;

 protected void link_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     ...
 }
```

When I run the application, the hyperlink is displayed, but nothing happens when I click on it. The `link_click` method is never reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
 richTextBox.IsDocumentEnabled = true
```

hold down *Ctrl* key and Click on the Hyperlink. It should work.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762271/clicking-hyperlinks-in-a-richtextbox-without-holding-down-ctrl-wpf) if you don't like to hold the Ctrl down.