# WPF interactive content (button, hyperlink etc) never works inside FlowDocument

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I must be missing something here. I've tried every possible way to make it so that *anything* is clickable inside a FlowDocument.

I've tried `<Hyperlink>` (along with every possible way to assign `NavigateUri`, `RequestNavigate` and even the `Hyperlink.Click` event - via XAML and  pure code-behind), and I've tried placing a button in a `<BlockUIContainer>` which still doesn't work.

The content renders correctly but clicking it does nothing.

I've also tried removing all `Style` options so it's nothing more than a FlowDocument with 'stuff' in it, and have tried setting the `RichTextBox` to `IsReadOnly=True/False`. But no luck!

Example below. Where that `<Hyperlink>` is, I've tried all possibilities, e.g. `<BlockUIContainer>` etc. The end result is always that the element renders in the correct way, but clicking has no result at all.

```
//XAML
 <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True">
     <FlowDocument>
         <Paragraph>
             1.1.3 Course technology requirements
         </Paragraph>
         <Paragraph>
             <Run>
                 Access to an internet connection and a standard, modern web 
                 browser are the only necessary requirements of the course. 
                 If you are using an old or outdated browser, such as Internet 
                 Explorer, you may need to update. We recommend
             </Run>

             <Hyperlink x:Name="GoogleChromeLink" 
                        NavigateUri="https://www.google.com/chrome/" 
                        RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" >
                Google Chrome.
            </Hyperlink>

        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox> 

// C#

private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [Clicking HyperLinks in a RichTextBox without holding down CTRL - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762271/clicking-hyperlinks-in-a-richtextbox-without-holding-down-ctrl-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

This solution saved the day: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6146387/5801881

I needed to add `IsDocumentEnabled="True"` to the RichTextBox element:

```
<RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True">
```