# hyperlink inside texbox in custom message box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom Message box ,i use to pop up my xml data inside th custom message box.

I have no idea how to hyper link some particular tag ,for me i need to hyperlink  tag in the data.

am populate the message inside textbox in my custom messgae box.

[image: Hyperlink]

```
public void Show (string text)
        {
            txtMessage.Text = text;
            //ChooseButtons(MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            this.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the RichTextBox Control. Take a look at the information in this link:

[How to: Display Web-Style Links with the Windows Forms RichTextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f591a55w.aspx#Y253)

-Amulya

Comment: Thanks Amulya but no code sample to get some understanding about how it works.

Comment: check this : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435607/c-how-can-i-make-a-hyperlink-work-in-a-richtextbox)