# How to click Windows 8 RichEditBox hyperlinks?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Maybe this is a stupid question, but how can I click (and capture the click event of) a link in a Windows 8 `RichEditBox`.

I've placed the link using `RichEditBox.Document.GetRange(0, 10).Link = "\"foobar\""`. The link itself is shown in the `RichEditBox`, but I can't click it.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a helper to add a link clicked event to the RichEditBox:

```
public class LinkClickedEventArgs
{
    public string LinkText { get; set; }
}

public class RichEditBoxWithHyperlink :RichEditBox
{

    public event EventHandler<LinkClickedEventArgs> LinkClicked;
    protected override void OnTapped(TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTapped(e);
        if (LinkClicked != null)
        {
            Point tappedPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            ITextRange textRange = this.Document.GetRangeFromPoint(tappedPoint, PointOptions.ClientCoordinates);
            textRange.StartOf(TextRangeUnit.Link,true);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textRange.Link))
            {
                LinkClicked(this, new LinkClickedEventArgs(){LinkText = textRange.Link});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Tapped event does not fire for me when the control is not enabled, and i *think* readonly. I ended up making a transparent control over it, and also using screen coordinates (GetPosition(null) and PointOptions.None) because they didn't seem to line up correctly for me. I was on windows phone 8.1 though, and I believe there's some functional differences to this control - it's converted to Xaml on desktop I've heard, but true Rtf on phone.

Answer (score 0):

`RichEditBox` lacks WPF's `RichTextBox`'s `LinkClicked` event. There is no way to detect whether the link was clicked or not. You can open the hyperlink only by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and clicking on link.

[How can I make a hyperlink work in a RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435607/c-sharp-how-can-i-make-a-hyperlink-work-in-a-richtextbox) - This what in WPF

Comment: Having the same issue too. I'm surprised Microsoft didn't make the RichEditBox a sealed class as they often do.