# How to make "links" added to the text?

Tags: c#, winforms

Made a button to add "links" to "richTextBox". 
"Links" are added not to the text, but from above "richTextBox".

Question
How to make the "links" added to the text based on the current code or based on another solution?

```
 LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();
        link.Text = "*** LINK ***";

        // link.LinkClicked
        link.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.link_LinkClicked);

        // data
        LinkLabel.Link data = new LinkLabel.Link();
        data.LinkData = @"C:\";

        // link
        link.Links.Add(data);
        link.AutoSize = true;
        link.Location =
            this.richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(this.richTextBox1.TextLength);

        // richTextBox1
        this.richTextBox1.Controls.Add(link);
        this.richTextBox1.AppendText(link.Text + "   ");
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = this.richTextBox1.TextLength;
```

[**GIF**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7QfG.gif)

Comment: Reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-display-web-style-links-with-the-windows-forms-richtextbox-control) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wronga approach. The text in `RichTextBox` is not parts of `Controls`, so if you add `LinkLabel` into `Controls`, their positions will not be synchronized.

Look at this question [How can I make a hyperlink work in a RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435607/how-can-i-make-a-hyperlink-work-in-a-richtextbox?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thank you.
I read it.
If I understand correctly, this solution is used if in the "RichTextBox" only the link.
I use the following text structure in "RichTextBox": "Line 1-Text, Line 2-Reference, Line 3-Text, Line 4-Reference"

I'm sorry if I did not understand something.
I'm an inexperienced programmer.

Comment: This approach will break in several cases. For example if you will show scroll the content. Or the system font (size) will be different. Or if one line will be wraped to next line, etc...

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the solution by [TcKs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20382/tcks), check this: [Links with arbitrary text in a RichTextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox)

An author of related article wrote:

> every time the text in the RichTextBox is changed, the text is parsed
>   for URLs and the matching text ranges are formatted as links
>   (underlined, blue foreground by default)