# 'The system cannot find the file specified' when clicking link

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core, hyperlink

I am following [this answer about making hyperlink work in a RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/435649/3416774) by adding this:

```cs
private void mRichTextBox_LinkClicked (object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText);
}
```

(Actually what I'm really doing is to go to the property of the control, click on the LinkClicked action, and just put the `Start()` method in there.)

However when clicking the link I get this error:
`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process 'https://example.com' with working directory 'XYZ'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .NET 6 or higher, try this:

```
 Process.Start( new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = e.LinkText ,  UseShellExecute = true } );
```

Comment: can you explain why it works?

Comment: @Ooker `UseShellExecute` true if the shell should be used when starting the process; false if the process should be created directly from the executable file. This link has good information for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-6.0

Comment: Is `ProcessStartInfo` a class or an object? It seems like to be an object for being the input of the method `Start()` and having the `{}`bracket, so why can it accept `new` before it?

Comment: @Ooker despite this being old, it still shows up in Google at the top. The `new ... {}` notation is shorthand - it's allows you to instantiate something with a list of properties already set (aka `a = new xy(); a.prop1 = 123; a.prop2 = 345;` is the same as `a = new xy{ prop1 = 123, prop2 = 123 };`. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers